# Filtering Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, typescript, date

I am trying to filter an array which contain date(converted from string) which is greater than a particular date..

```
_this.downloadData.forEach(_d => _d.LogTime = _d.LogTime.toString());

console.log(_this.downloadData.filter(x=>new Date(x.LogTime) > new Date('3/11/2019 7:29:12 AM')));
```

> But filter always return zero items

.

Array looks like below:

```
[0 … 99]
0:
CPUStat:""
Connectivity:""
DiskStatus:""
HostName:"HOSTname"
LastRebootStatus:null
LogTime:"Mon Mar 11 2019 07:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

__proto__:
Object
```

Comment: No even i have many records greater than and less thanDate('3/11/2019 7:29:12 AM') none of them filter , always return zero

Comment: Did you check the date in array after converting it to string value?

Comment: LogTime:"Mon Mar 11 2019 07:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" this is the value after converting

Comment: What absolute time are you expecting `new Date('3/11/2019 7:29:12 AM')` to be?  It doesn't indicate a time zone.

Comment: its client side scrpting so zone doesnt matter i hope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your problem here consist of the date time format not being ISO 8601 compliant.  Because of this you need to clean up the date. `LogTime.substring(4,23) + obj.LogTime.substring(28,33)` will get the important parts from your string. Then you can use `moment.js` (https://momentjs.com), which is a must for handling time in JavaScript.

You can run the code below and see that it works

```js
// Your example time array
let timeArray = [
  { LogTime:"Mon Mar 11 2019 07:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" },
  { LogTime:"Mon Mar 11 2019 08:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" },
  { LogTime:"Mon Mar 11 2019 09:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" },
  { LogTime:"Mon Mar 11 2019 10:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" }
 ],
 format = "MMM MM YYYY HH:mm:ssZ",
    shouldBeAfter = moment('Mar 11 2019 09:00:12+0530', format),
    result,
    filterDateGreaterThan = function (obj){
      let sDate,
          mDate;
      
      sDate = obj.LogTime.substring(4,23) + obj.LogTime.substring(28,33);
      mDate = moment(sDate, format);
      // console.log(mDate);
      return mDate.isAfter(shouldBeAfter);
    };
 result = timeArray.filter(filterDateGreaterThan);
 console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Code when not using Moment.js

```js
// Your example time array
let timeArray = [
  { LogTime:"Mon Mar 11 2019 07:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" },
  { LogTime:"Mon Mar 11 2019 08:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" },
  { LogTime:"Mon Mar 11 2019 09:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" },
  { LogTime:"Mon Mar 11 2019 10:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" }
 ],
    shouldBeAfter = new Date('Mar 11 2019 09:00:12+0530'),
    result,
    filterDateGreaterThan = function (obj){
      let sDate,
          date;
      
      sDate = obj.LogTime.substring(4,23) + obj.LogTime.substring(28,33);
      date = new Date(sDate);
      return date.valueOf() > shouldBeAfter.valueOf();
    };
 result = timeArray.filter(filterDateGreaterThan);
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: is there any way without doing this moment?

Comment: i cannot use another component in code as it require multiple approvals

Comment: Yes, I have added code above. Remember that the JS doc is your best friend (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: You are really a superstar!! Mind-blowing answer ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix your problem by adding a timezone to your input. If you don't provide a timezone, your browser will use your local timezone. For instance, my timezone is PDT, so I end up seeing this:

```
Without Timezone in input:
input  : 3/11/2019 7:29:12 AM
output : Mon Mar 11 2019 07:29:12 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

With Timezone in input:
input  : Mon Mar 11 2019 07:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
output : Sun Mar 10 2019 19:09:12 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Note that with the timezone in your input, the unix timestamp matches the output.

---

I personally use [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to handle these cases.

```
Without Timezone in input:
input  : moment.tz("3/11/2019 7:29:12 AM", "Asia/Calcutta").toDate();
output : Mon Mar 11 2019 00:29:12 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

With Timezone in input:
input  : moment.tz("Mon Mar 11 2019 07:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", "Asia/Calcutta").toDate();
output : Mon Mar 11 2019 00:39:12 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Comment: i tried  console.log(_this.downloadData.filter(x=>new Date(x.LogTime)=== "Wed Nov 14 2018 06:02:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"));

but not worked